# not able to execute multiple async task in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why i am not able to exceute 2 aysnctask simultaneously, here is the code that i am using, the problem is its not excuting. I tired to disable the first task as well but wasnt able to find the second task being executed.

```
new CallXML().execute();  
new ImageThread().execute();
```

Comment: There should be a StackTrace. Post it.

Comment: Show the code of CallXML and ImageThread please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

just call another thread in postexecute of previous thread.